How to take Docker Desktop full backup and restore
How to take a full backup and restore of Docker Desktop. I see that there is a way to save the Docker image as a tar file in the local filesystem.
I was looking to dump all the current images into one single tar file as a backup for the current status of the docker desktop
To save a docker image
% docker save image-name | gzip > image-name.tar.gz

I am not aware how to restore it, again this is only one image I have almost ~30 odd images, can I take a backup in a single file
